# getJSON error - not sure where I'm going wrong

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

With the help of a few other stack users I have come up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ywLq/

I want to use an external json file & come up with something similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RCB9M/

The file I am linking to at the moment is: http://www.lofiz.co.uk/afba/songkickwidget/testjsondata.json but this will ultimately change to a Songkick JSON output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a victim of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The browser will by default block JSON that is fetched cross-domain for security reasons. If you need to get data cross-domain, you will either have to implement a server-side proxy, or use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), if the data is provided in that format as well. If the source doesn't provide data in JSONP, I believe you could utilize [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to convert it.

Resource on JSONP: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

**Update:** Your URL would be called like this:

```
​$(function(){
  var url = "https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/253846/calendar.json?apikey=HlgKnFaq9qYO1h9T&jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    // Do what you want to do with the return data within this callback
    console.log(data);        
  });
});​
```

**Update 2:**

I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ywLq/3/) to work with `getJSON()`. I also took the liberty to make a few other changes:

1. I modified how you defined your array of month-names, to make it more readable.
2. `.getDay()` in JavaScript is used to return the day of the week (0 = sunday, 1 = monday and so on), as I believe you want the day of the month, you should use `.getDate()` instead. See my JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, I've read about that on Songkicks website (http://www.songkick.com/developer/upcoming-events-for-artist). Would this URL be appropriate (https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/253846/calendar.json?apikey=HlgKnFaq9qYO1h9T&jsoncallback=?) and if so could you show me on the jsfiddle links?

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I'm a little clearer now - I hope to be able to learn this properly in time. So at the moment I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pr2GU/ The JSLint is saying there is an error in the var month = new Array(); line but I don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: @redditor Change the line `var month = new Array();` to `var month = [];` and you should be fine. Your way is correct as well, but JSLint prefer the array literal notation.

Comment: I think I understand the getJSON now, would it be possible for you to edit this for me, with the corrrect way of calling getJSON? Thank you http://jsfiddle.net/9ywLq/

Comment: @redditor I have updated my answer again with a working fiddle that uses `.getJSON()`, and with a couple of other improvments as well.